# In Markdown, is there an official best practice as relates to line length?

Tags: github, markdown

I txt files, and when writing code, it seems to be accepted best practice to use 80-characters per line. This also applies to lines of text in a paragraph. If my paragraph contains 320 characters, it should be written as three separate lines. Is there a markdown standard that defines whether or not this is best practice, for example for GitHub README.md files?

Comment: I strongly oppose the 80-character line length to be an accepted best practice. Even the Python team brought themself to allow 100 chars for teams that don't like 80. And PEP8 is the strongest style guide I am aware of ;-)

Comment: Discussion on wrapping (apparently per sentence) or not: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/10/11/wrapping-text/

Answer (score 14):

There is no best practice for wrapping in Markdown. The only mention of wrapping in [the original spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) says that hard wrapping is permitted:

> The implication of the "one or more consecutive lines of text" rule is that Markdown supports "hard-wrapped" text paragraphs.

Similarly, the [CommonMark spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/) and the [GitHub Flavored Markdown page](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) make no mention of a best practice when it comes to hard wrapping. There are many other implementations of Markdown, but I suspect that most take the same approach.

Certainly some *projects* might have best practices, but they will vary.